# How to encrypt a string in Java by just using a password?

Tags: java, string, encryption, password-hash

I'm developing an application where I need to encrypt text using a user-entered password (as a key) and store it. User can decrypt his data whenever he wants by entering the password. The security of the data should depend upon the complexity and length of the password.

I have used AES before but here I can't use it as the encryption key in AES has to be of a specific length. I want something where the encryption key could be of any length.

I just can't figure out which encryption method or algorithm to use.

Comment: its a "common(good!) practice": not to use "a user password" (as "the key"), but a (*standard length*) **hash function** *of it*...(matching your key length requirements)!

Comment: Creating a zip file with password is a good solution to you? If so, try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minizip-asm.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for [PBKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) - password based key derivation function. Please note - passwords are not keys (passwords are having different length and usually less entropy).

Though you may derive a key from the password. Commonly used password-based key derivation functions used today are PBKDF2, Argon2, BCrypt or SCrypt. Just search for them.

You may check some [examples](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/)

```
IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(psswdSalt, PBKDF_INTERATIONS, ivParamSpec);
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory pbeKeyFactory = 
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
SecretKey pbeKey = pbeKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(PBE_CIPHER_NAME);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
```

---

In theory - you may use a simple hash (e.g. sha-256) and take only necessary number of bits to derive a key. The issue is that the password are usually not that random if it is easy for a human to remember; this means that they are vulnerable to brute-force attacks or dictionary attacks.